# Maven How to use dependencies of a jar project defined as a dependency of a war project

Tags: java, maven

I have two projects a war project(A) and a jar project(B). 
  War project is dependent on jar project and 
  dependency in pom.xml of A is defined as

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>a.b.c</groupId>
            <artifactId>B-core</artifactId>
            <version>${B-core-version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Now when I build War Project A, I wish that 
  I dont need to define the dependencies
  already defined in B e;g

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

defined in pom of Jar Project B should be Available for Project A. 
  But what is currently happening is  I have to repeat the dependencies 
  in both the projects. Is there a way around for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a jar of B project, install it in maven repository and then add a new dependency in war B project's pom.xml.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>a.b.c</groupId>
        <artifactId>B-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

---

--EDIT--

By removing `<scope>test</scope>` will solve your problem.

For more information read about [Introduction to the Dependency Mechanism](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)

Comment: Thanks.If you mean to add B as a dependency in A that is what I am doing. But I have to repeat the dependencies in A which I defined for B.

Comment: Yes you are right. Let me test it by creating a sample project. It is some thing related to `<scope>test</scope>`. can you remove this line?

Comment: Read it here about [How do optional dependencies work?](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot.Removing <scope>test</scope> works perfectly fine.

Comment: Can you please edit it your post above with this answer so that I can mark it as right answer

Comment: sure why not. I will update it to make it helpful for others also.